# Total War: Warhammer, Difference between story and grand campaign

Tags: warhammer-total-war

I was wondering if there is any difference between the grand campaign and story campaign of the wood elves and beastmen. As they have their own seperate tab in the main menu.

Comment: I haven't played the beastmen campaign but in the wood elves one there are a lot more elven town than the original, and your enemies are mostly beastmen, unless you messed up your diplomacy with the bretonnia factions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wood Elves and Beastmen DLC came with the faction for the grand campaign but also their own mini-campaign taking place on a small part of the grand map (but a lot more detailed so there are more towns).

For example the Beastmen mini-campaign An Eye for an Eye takes place in the human provinces north of Altdorf, around Midenheim.

The mini campaigns use similar mechanisms to the grand campaign but feature specific characters, subfactions, quests and objectives. The mini campaigns are usually shorter than doing the grand campaign.